# How is the idea of "girlfriend material" naturally expressed in German?

Tags: expression, english, french

> Elle n'est pas de l'**étoffe** dont on fait les copines...

- {literally}: *She's not of the material from which we make girlfriends.*

То express the idea of "*she's not (X)girlfriend material*", "*she's not cut out to be anyone's (X)girlfriend*", in French you say something like above with the word "*étoffe*" corresponding to "*material* / *fabric*".

In conversation, I'd probably say something like:

> – **Gibt** ‘ne gute Freundin **ab**, oder?
>
> – Ganz und gar nicht!

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in German?

Comment: "Schwiegertochtermaterial" hab' ich schon mal gehört. "Freundinnenmaterial" noch nie.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a literal translation for [girlfriend material](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=girlfriend%20material). Funny enough girlfriend-material/boyfriend-material was a 2018 [suggestion](https://www.morgenpost.de/vermischtes/article215196671/Jugendwort-des-Jahres-Diese-Begriffe-sind-nominiert.html) for the "Jugendwort des Jahres", explained as

> Mann/Frau, der/die sich für eine Beziehung eignet

so maybe it's best to use the English expression. Germans like hip English words ;) .

---

But if you insist. German expressions can be

> taugt als Freundin
>
> gibt 'ne gute Freundin ab (as you said)
>
> eignet sich als Freundin
>
> mit der könnte ich mir eine Beziehung vorstellen

or when you look at what someone has to be for [girlfriend material](https://www.bedeutungonline.de/was-bedeutet-boyfriend-material-girlfriend-material-auf-deutsch-bedeutung-und-definition-erklaert/)

> sie ist (für mich) beziehungstauglich / beziehungsgeeignet

But watch out: *beziehungstauglich* can be negatively connoted. Especially because of its counterpart, which is usually used as a selfexplanitory

> Ich bin beziehungsuntauglich (My traits make me a person not suitable for a partnership)

Comment: "das Zeug zu X haben" is also popular.